# override malloc and new calls in cpp program

Tags: c++, linker, g++, malloc, ld

I want to call my custom malloc/new calls instead of standard library functions.
**1.** for malloc, I have this short program

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void *__real_malloc(size_t size);

    void *__wrap_malloc(size_t size)
    {
        void *ptr = __real_malloc(size);
        printf("malloc(%ld) = %p\n", size, ptr);
        return ptr;
    }

    int main(void) {
      int* ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
      return 0;
    }
```

I use the following command to compile
`g++ -Wl,--wrap,malloc main.cpp`
But getting below error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccnB04KY.o: in function `__wrap_malloc(unsigned long)':
b3.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `__real_malloc(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccnB04KY.o: in function `main':
b3.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `__wrap_malloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This works with gcc for .c files but not with g++ and .cpp files. What's the issue?

**2.** Also I cant figure out how to overide new calls?

Comment: _"...Also I cant figure out how to overide new calls?..."_ - _"...Versions (1-8) are replaceable: a __user-provided__ non-member function with the same signature defined anywhere in the program, in any source file, replaces the default version...."_ __note:__ read the _"...(since C++11).."_ just below the quoted text https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: Names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__real_malloc`, `__wrap_malloc`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Also, names that begin with an underscore followed by a lowercase letter are reserved in the global namespace.  (Okay to use them as member variable (or member functions, but that's not very conventional) or local variables or parameters.)

Comment: @PeteBecker: I don't see how you can avoid it here - the two prefixes are prescribed by the implementation itself. That is why the implementation uses those two prefixes from its own reserved names.

Comment: @MSalters -- there's nothing in the question that says that.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The `ld` documentation for `-wrap` does, and the question says that `g++ -Wl,--wrap,malloc` is used.

Comment: @MSalters -- <shrug> questions about compiler-specific stuff should clearly state what compiler is being used and why, so that they don't confuse casual readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why does `g++` not work with `-Wl,--wrap,malloc`?

`g++` implies C++, and C++ ABI is different from C ABI. So you need to add `extern "C"` around `__real_malloc` and `__wrap_malloc`:

```cpp
extern "C" {
void *__real_malloc(size_t size);

void *__wrap_malloc(size_t size) {
  void *ptr = __real_malloc(size);
  printf("malloc(%ld) = %p\n", size, ptr);
  return ptr;
}
}
```

To avoid conflicts, C++ compilers rewrite names to "random" (but it's not) strings. This is called [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and it encodes information about namespaces, function arguments (because you can overload functions in C++ and linkers require unique names for each one of them), etc. In comparison, C compilers translate the name to the assembly without much change. [This Compiler Explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/YrzsWbMh8) shows that x86 msvc compiler inserts a `_` before the function name, while the other 3 compilers (x64 msvc, x86-64 gcc, and x86-64 clang) keeps the original name defined in C.

`-Wl,--wrap,malloc` is an option passed to the linker, which asks the linker to look for a function named `__wrap_malloc`. With `extern "C"`, g++ generates names as if the function is defined in a C source file so the linker can find it.

## How to override `new`?

You can override `new` specifically for a class, or provide a global `new`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new.

Comment: There is no ABI that is "default for C"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using glibc then you can use the GNU extensions for malloc: man malloc_hook

```
   #include <malloc.h>

   void *(*__malloc_hook)(size_t size, const void *caller);

   void *(*__realloc_hook)(void *ptr, size_t size, const void *caller);

   void *(*__memalign_hook)(size_t alignment, size_t size,
                            const void *caller);

   void (*__free_hook)(void *ptr, const void *caller);

   void (*__malloc_initialize_hook)(void);

   void (*__after_morecore_hook)(void);
```

For `new` you can provide a global new. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers show why `-Wl,--wrap,malloc` didn't work.

But note that after you make it work, your code is very likely to *crash* due to stack overflow.

This is because `printf` can (and does under some conditions) call `malloc` itself, and when that happens, infinite recursion is very likely.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is wondering how to override all allocator functions, [Here is a list](https://microsoft.github.io/mimalloc/overrides.html) of all functions that [*mimalloc*](https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc) (MIT license) from Microsoft overrides:

```cpp
// C
void*  malloc(size_t size);
void*  calloc(size_t size, size_t n);
void*  realloc(void* p, size_t newsize);
void   free(void* p);
 
void*  aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size);
char*  strdup(const char* s);
char*  strndup(const char* s, size_t n);
char*  realpath(const char* fname, char* resolved_name);
 
 
// C++
void   operator delete(void* p);
void   operator delete[](void* p);
 
void*  operator new(std::size_t n) noexcept(false);
void*  operator new[](std::size_t n) noexcept(false);
void*  operator new( std::size_t n, std::align_val_t align) noexcept(false);
void*  operator new[]( std::size_t n, std::align_val_t align) noexcept(false);
 
void*  operator new  ( std::size_t count, const std::nothrow_t& tag);
void*  operator new[]( std::size_t count, const std::nothrow_t& tag);
void*  operator new  ( std::size_t count, std::align_val_t al, const std::nothrow_t&);
void*  operator new[]( std::size_t count, std::align_val_t al, const std::nothrow_t&);
 
// Posix
int    posix_memalign(void** p, size_t alignment, size_t size);
 
// Linux
void*  memalign(size_t alignment, size_t size);
void*  valloc(size_t size);
void*  pvalloc(size_t size);
size_t malloc_usable_size(void *p);
void*  reallocf(void* p, size_t newsize);
 
// macOS
void   vfree(void* p);
size_t malloc_size(const void* p);
size_t malloc_good_size(size_t size);
 
// BSD
void*  reallocarray( void* p, size_t count, size_t size );
void*  reallocf(void* p, size_t newsize);
void   cfree(void* p);
 
// NetBSD
int    reallocarr(void* p, size_t count, size_t size);
 
// Windows
void*  _expand(void* p, size_t newsize);
size_t _msize(void* p);
 
void*  _malloc_dbg(size_t size, int block_type, const char* fname, int line);
void*  _realloc_dbg(void* p, size_t newsize, int block_type, const char* fname, int line);
void*  _calloc_dbg(size_t count, size_t size, int block_type, const char* fname, int line);
void*  _expand_dbg(void* p, size_t size, int block_type, const char* fname, int line);
size_t _msize_dbg(void* p, int block_type);
void   _free_dbg(void* p, int block_type);
```

These overrides are redirected to the *mimalloc* library in [mimalloc/src/alloc-override.c](https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc/blob/master/src/alloc-override.c). Some important functions are:

```cpp
mi_malloc
mi_calloc
mi_realloc
mi_reallocarr
mi_reallocf
mi_reallocarray
mi_valloc

mi_free
mi_free_aligned
mi_cfree

mi_new
mi_new_nothrow
mi_new_aligned
mi_new_aligned_nothrow

mi_posix_memalign
mi_memalign
mi_aligned_alloc
mi_pvalloc
```

So to override all relevant functions, customizing these entries may be another good way to figure it out.